# I'm having trouble with react-datepicker position

Tags: css, reactjs, react-datepicker

I'm using react-datepicker but for some reason it is showing the calendar behind a container.

[image]

I have tried:

```
.react-datepicker-popper {
  z-index: 9999 !important;
}
```

but it doesn't work.

Here is the Date Picker component

```
<DatePicker
     selected={startDateSingleDay}
     onChange={onChangeDatePickerStartDateSingleDay}
     dateFormat="yyyy-MM-dd"
     className="text-center"
     showMonthDropdown
     showYearDropdown
     dropdownMode="select"
     onChangeRaw={handleDateChangeRaw}
     popperClassName="date-picker-reports"
     placeholderText="Choose a date"
   />
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Try to change the CSS styles directly from Dev Tools and then apply what works into your JS/CSS files.

Comment: Has the container the `position: relative` style?

Comment: @emi yes, I've tried that but the className for the datepicker, `which is .react-datepicker-popper` does not apply the z-index property.

Comment: @AlexeyKorkoza I've tried `position: relative` and also without it, and I got the same results

Comment: @Alex Yepes It's hard to answer your question. So, I think you should post your code in your question. In this case, we will be able to help you quickly than now.

Comment: @AlexeyKorkoza Thanks, after doing some research I finally found the problem, and I posted an answer describing it

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I fixed it as react-popper will place the popover in the same constraints as the
parent div. For cases where the parent div is somehow constrained -- a
scrollable div -- the popper will appear inside the div and will be
constrained by it to.

In my case I wanted the popover to be unconstrained it's
parent. To fix this, I placed the popover in a container outside of
the constrained container.

```
import { Portal } from "react-overlays";

const CalendarContainer = ({ children }) => {
  const el = document.getElementById("calendar-portal");

  return <Portal container={el}>{children}</Portal>;
};
```

And added the popperContainer prop to the DatePicker like so:

```
<DatePicker
    selected={startDate}
    onChange={onChangeDatePickerStartDate}
    dateFormat="yyyy-MM-dd"
    className="text-center date-picker-reports"
    showMonthDropdown
    showYearDropdown
    dropdownMode="select"
    onChangeRaw={handleDateChangeRaw}
    popperPlacement="top-start"
    placeholderText="Choose a start date"
    popperContainer={CalendarContainer}
/>
```

Final Result:

[image]

Answer (score 22):

This is tested for react-datepicker 4.2.1

Adding a prop portalId should automatically fix the issue.

According to its documentation If the provided portalId cannot be found in the dom, one will be created by default with that id passed in the prop.

```
<DatePicker
 portalId="root-portal"
 selected={startDateSingleDay}
 onChange={onChangeDatePickerStartDateSingleDay}
 dateFormat="yyyy-MM-dd"
 className="text-center"
 showMonthDropdown
 showYearDropdown
 dropdownMode="select"
 onChangeRaw={handleDateChangeRaw}
 popperClassName="date-picker-reports"
 placeholderText="Choose a date" 
/>
```

Comment: This fixed it for me.

Comment: @Anil, Yes it fixed the hide/show overlaying issue. But it doesn't trigger clicks on the dates. It only closes the popup everytime when anything clicked inside the popup.

Comment: @SKR Can you provide more information about the issue you are facing ? A codesandbox link to reproduce the issue should be great.

Comment: I was using OutsideClickHandler plugin which was triggering the click inside the portal as outside click, so, I needed to handle the same. no other issues right now. @Anil

Comment: `portalId="root-portal"` for the win! I spent hours and hours searching this. Note I didn't have any issues with triggering clicks on the dates.

Answer (score 5):

[in material table i'm facing same issue.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z0dqY.png)

popperProps={{strategy: 'fixed'}} by using this datepicker property [this is how we can use in code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eiGpZ.png)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31477146)

Answer (score 1):

```
<DatePicker minDate={new Date()} 
  selected={new Date()} 
  onChange={this.setDueDate} 
  dateFormat='dd/MM/yyyy' 
  popperPlacement="bottom" 
  popperModifiers={{ flip: { behavior: ["bottom"] }, preventOverflow: { enabled: false }, hide: { enabled: false } }} 
/>
```

Answer (score 1):

I found a 100% working solution as it is in `react-datepicker` official documentation in [here](https://reactdatepicker.com/#example-configure-popper-properties).

Put these 3 props `popperClassName`, `popperPlacement`, `popperModifiers` as it is in the following and the datepicker will work astonishingly.

```
<DatePicker
      selected={startDate}
      onChange={(date) => setStartDate(date)}
      popperClassName="some-custom-class"
      popperPlacement="top-end"
      popperModifiers={[
        {
          name: "offset",
          options: {
            offset: [5, 10],
          },
        },
        {
          name: "preventOverflow",
          options: {
            rootBoundary: "viewport",
            tether: false,
            altAxis: true,
          },
        },
      ]}
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

As react-datepicker uses popperjs internally, we can even use `popperPrpps` prop with `strategy: 'fixed'` or `positionFixed: true` for older version of popperjs.